# Automated SMTP (not MAPI) emails using SQL Server Job Scheduler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Work on SQL Server 2000.i want to send birthday wishes to all customers whose birthday matches the current day.I have created a database Customers with a table called CustomerDetails with the following fields

1. ID
2. Name
3. BirthDate
4. Email

I have written the SQL script shown below. The SQL script loops through the CustomerDetails table and matches all records birth day and birth month with the current day and month. If the two matches then it sends an email to the particular customer to its email address stored in the table.

```
DECLARE 
@out_desc VARCHAR(1000),
@out_mesg VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20),
@birthdate datetime,
@email NVARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [name], [birthdate], [email]
FROM Customers

OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 
@name, @birthdate, @email
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF DATEPART(DAY,@birthdate) = DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(MONTH,@birthdate) = DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())
    BEGIN
        SET @body = '<b>Happy Birthday ' + @name + '</b><br />Many happy returns of the day'
        + '<br /><br />Customer Relationship Department'
        EXEC sp_send_mail 
        'shamim@sew.com', --- add your Email Address here
        'shamim007',       ----add your Password here
        @email,
        'Birthday Wishes', 
        @body,
        'htmlbody', @output_mesg = @out_mesg output, @output_desc = @out_desc output

        PRINT @out_mesg
        PRINT @out_desc
    END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO 
    @name, @birthdate, @email
END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
```

**Stored procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_send_mail]
        @from varchar(500) ,
        @password varchar(500) ,
        @to varchar(500) ,      
        @subject varchar(500),
        @body varchar(4000) ,
        @bodytype varchar(10),
        @output_mesg varchar(10) output,
        @output_desc varchar(1000) output
AS
DECLARE @imsg int
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @source varchar(255)
DECLARE @description varchar(500)

EXEC @hr = sp_oacreate 'cdo.message', @imsg out

--SendUsing Specifies Whether to send using port (2) or using pickup directory (1)
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg,
'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").value','2'

--SMTP Server
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").value', 
  'smtp.mail.me.net' 

--UserName
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername").value', 
  @from 

--Password
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword").value', 
  @password 

--UseSSL
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl").value', 
  'True' 

--PORT 
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport").value', 
  '465' 

--Requires Aunthentication None(0) / Basic(1)
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 
  'configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate").value', 
  '1' 

EXEC @hr = sp_oamethod @imsg, 'configuration.fields.update', null
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 'to', @to
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 'from', @from
EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, 'subject', @subject

-- if you are using html e-mail, use 'htmlbody' instead of 'textbody'.

EXEC @hr = sp_oasetproperty @imsg, @bodytype, @body
EXEC @hr = sp_oamethod @imsg, 'send', null

SET @output_mesg = 'Success'

-- sample error handling.
IF @hr <>0 
    SELECT @hr
    BEGIN
        EXEC @hr = sp_oageterrorinfo null, @source out, @description out
        IF @hr = 0
        BEGIN
            --set @output_desc = ' source: ' + @source
            set @output_desc =  @description
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @output_desc = ' sp_oageterrorinfo failed'
    END
    IF not @output_desc is NULL
            SET @output_mesg = 'Error'
END
EXEC @hr = sp_oadestroy @imsg
GO
```

why mail not send , what's the problem...How to solve it .

Answer (score 2):

On SQL Server 2000 if I could not use MAPI/`xp_sendmail`, I would use [`xp_smtp_sendmail (IE only!)`](http://www.sqldev.net/xp/xpsmtp.htm) to use SMTP rather than writing my own using `sp_OA%`.

You haven't given us any error messages or log entries etc, so all I can is that you try this tried-and-tested extended stored proc.